# Encryption warnings from AspNetCore.DataProtection on AWS Lambda

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda

Building a simple web api. ASP.NET Core 6 on AWS Lambda (`Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer` 7.2).

I get these 3 warnings from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection`, on every cold start:

```
Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
No XML encryptor configured. Key <Guid> may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
```

I found other StackOverflow users asking about this, but they are trying to fix the secrets repository. I just don't want it at all. (AWS Lambda - I'm aiming for stateless)

Can I find out what it's trying to store? I am not using sessions.

Can I tell it that ephemeral storage is ok, and no warnings are required? Tried `services.AddDataProtection().UseEphemeralDataProtectionProvider()` but it does not stop the warnings.

Comment: Did you happen to find an an answer to this?

Comment: Thanks for the ping @Charles. We were able to silence the warnings but it took a hack. Just added an answer.

Comment: FYI: Dug into this myself some more, the reason `services.AddDataProtection().UseEphemeralDataProtectionProvider()` doesn't make a difference is that a `EphemeralDataProtectionProvider` isn't the same thing as a `EphemeralXmlRepository` which is throwing the 2nd warning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still playing around with this...

Adding the following:

```
var keyRingPath = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}";

var _ = Directory.CreateDirectory(keyRingPath);

services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keyRingPath));
```

As an alternative, you can make sure the environment variable
`LOCALAPPDATA` is set to something like `"/tmp/my-app-name/"`

Either will get rid of the first two messages...

```
Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.   
Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
```

I would imagine that adding a `.ProtectKeysWithCertificate(<my x.509 cert>)`
Would get rid of the 3rd.

But where to get that cert?
Load from a file?  Probably not.
Secrets service?  Maybe?
AWS KMS key somehow?  Possibly?

**Updated 2024-02-29**
Apparently there's a [AWS Systems Manager ASP.NET Core Data Protection Provider](https://github.com/aws/aws-ssm-data-protection-provider-for-aspnet) package that:

> allows you to use AWS Systems Manager's Parameter Store to store keys
> generated by ASP.NET's Data Protection API. This enables you to scale
> by allowing multiple web servers to share the keys.

Still feels like overkill for keys that my Lambda doesn't actually make use of.  And no idea about overhead as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

We were finally able to silence the warnings via `appsettings.json`.

You might find this works on its own. In our environment we also needed a manual reload hack (as example below) - **We had a version mismatch between `NLog.Extensions.Logging` and `NLog`**, this might have been part of our problem.

```cs
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class LambdaEntryPoint : Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction
{
    protected override void Init(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // ... do all the rest of Init ...

        ResetLogFilters(builder);
    }

    private IHostBuilder ResetLogFilters(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                // Throw away whatever is configured
                logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(c =>
                {
                    c.Rules.Clear();
                });

                // Start again
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            });
    }
}
```

appsettings.json (partial):

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection": "Error",
    }
  }
}
```